# split working for-loop calling JSON in 2 parts with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I have a working loop for a JSON call which loads the `data.root.offer[0].region` call into a div with class `.region` within another div `.carousel` It looks like this:

```
  $.getJSON('json/data.json', function(data) {
      var regions = $('.carousel .region').length;
      for (var i = 0; i <= regions; i++) {
        $('.region').eq(i).html('<p>' + data.root.offer[i].region + '</p>');
      };
});
```

When I run this, it only applies to the top carousel

I have been trying to duplicate the loop that loads the 8 items in the offer array into 8 divs divided with the `.region` class within 2 other divs with the `.carousel` class.

Copying the loop and changing the `i` doesnt work.. I tried changing class names too but no result.. If anybody knows a solution that'd be really helpful.

JSON

```
{"root": {"offer": [{"region": "Miami - Miami Beach",
                     "region": "Mexico - Playacar",
                     "region": "Cuba - Veradero",
                     "region": "Jamaica - Montego Bay",
                     "region": "Dominican Republic - Bavaro",
                     "region": "Turkije - Belek",
                     "region": "Turkije - Belek",
                     "region": "Turkije - Side",
                     "region": "Tunesië - Hammamet Yasmine ",
                     "region": "Egypte - Sharm El Sheikh"
}]}}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="carousel" tabindex="4">
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="region">
                    <p>miami beach1<p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="region">
                    <p>miami beach2<p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="region">
                    <p>miami beach3<p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="region">
                    <p>miami beach4<p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel" tabindex="4">
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="region">
                    <p>miami beach5<p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="region">
                    <p>miami beach6<p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="region">
                    <p>miami beach7<p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="region">
                    <p>miami beach8<p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what does the console say? you are iterating from 0 to length, you should be iterating from 0 to length-1. Don't you get a fatal error that prevents the rest of the script from executing?

Comment: Also, you use a $('.carousel .region') selector for the size and then you iterate over a list obtained using a different $('.region') selector using that size as the limit, which makes no sense at all. What do you intend by that?

Comment: this is what it logs: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'region' of undefined(anonymous function) @ main.js:13m.Callbacks.j @ jquery.1.11.1.min.js:2m.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery.1.11.1.min.js:2x @ jquery.1.11.1.min.js:4m.ajaxTransport.send.b @ jquery.1.11.1.min.js:4

Comment: I changed the html, the code worked fine if it was only one carousel, now I want to make it work on 2, and thats why I have to adapt the Jquery

Comment: can you have different classes for different carousals, depending on that code changes

Comment: yes thats no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
   /* $.getJSON('http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/Fx2DlmM', function(data) {
      var regions = $('.carousel .region').length;
      for (var i = 0; i < regions; i++) {
        $('.region').eq(i).html('<p>' + data.root.offer[i].region + '</p>');
      };
    }); */

    //if diff classes

   $.getJSON('http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/Fx2DlmM', function(data) {
      var $carousel1 = $('.carousel1 .region');
      var $carousel2 = $('.carousel2 .region');
      var offers = data.root.offer;
      var regions = $('.region').length;
      for (var i = 0; i < regions/2; i++) {
        $carousel1.eq(i).html('<p>' + offers[i].region + '</p>');
      }
      for (var j = 0; j < regions/2; j++,i++) {
        $carousel2.eq(j).html('<p>' + offers[i].region + '</p>');
      }
    });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Carousal 1<div class="carousel1" tabindex="4">
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="region">
                    <p>miami beach1<p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="region">
                    <p>miami beach2<p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="region">
                    <p>miami beach3<p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="region">
                    <p>miami beach4<p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
 Carousal 2   <div class="carousel2" tabindex="4">
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="region">
                    <p>miami beach5<p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="region">
                    <p>miami beach6<p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="region">
                    <p>miami beach7<p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="region">
                    <p>miami beach8<p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: not sure with your actual requirement but does above result matches your requirement else please explain what is your expected result/ carousal should look like

Comment: updated the answer with both code snippets, with same classes and with different classes. Confirm if it solves your problem then would provide you the optimized code, didnt feel to optimize before confirming whats required.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things wrong with your code:

First, the json you provide is not valid (property region gets repited). Try this instead:

```
{
  "root": {
    "offer": [
      {
        "region": "Miami - Miami Beach"
      },
      {
        "region": "Mexico - Playacar"
      },
      {
        "region": "Cuba - Veradero"
      },
      {
        "region": "Jamaica - Montego Bay"
      },
      {
        "region": "Dominican Republic - Bavaro"
      },
      {
        "region": "Turkije - Belek"
      },
      {
        "region": "Turkije - Belek"
      },
      {
        "region": "Turkije - Side"
      },
      {
        "region": "Tunesië - Hammamet Yasmine "
      },
      {
        "region": "Egypte - Sharm El Sheikh"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then, there are some issues in your js:

```
$.getJSON('json/data.json', function(data) {

      var regions = $('.carousel .region').length; 

      // wrong limit. data.root.offer[regions] does not exist. Try this instead:
      for (var i = 0; i < regions; i++) {

        // wrong selector. Be consistent and try this instead:
        $('.carousel .region').eq(i).html('<p>' + data.root.offer[i].region + '</p>');

      };

});
```

Also, you may want to use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) instead to select and perform an operation over a bunch of elements, and you should protect your code from a short / non existent array. Like this:

```js
$(function(){
    $.getJSON('http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/LFdizev', function(data) {
      $('.carousel .region').each(function(i, el){
       try {
         $(this).html('<p>' + data.root.offer[i].region + '</p>');
       } catch (e) {
         // handle size mismatch
       }
      });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Carousal 1<div class="carousel" tabindex="4">
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="region">
                    <p>miami beach1<p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="region">
                    <p>miami beach2<p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="region">
                    <p>miami beach3<p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="region">
                    <p>miami beach4<p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
 Carousal 2   <div class="carousel" tabindex="4">
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="region">
                    <p>miami beach5<p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="region">
                    <p>miami beach6<p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="region">
                    <p>miami beach7<p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frame">
                <div class="region">
                    <p>miami beach8<p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `.each` function also provides `index`, no need to use separate `i` index variable. like this `.each(function(index, ele)`.

Comment: nice observation. Good to know  :-)